# SQL Best way to get frequency of elements in array column

Tags: sql, presto

SQL Noob question here

I have an SQL table of the form

```
|id | array  |
|---|--------|
|1  | [1,2,3]|
|2  | [2,3,4]|
|2  | [2,5]  |
```

and I would like to get the frequency of the values that appear in the arrays of the *array* column. For the example table I would like to get something like

```
|value | frequency |
|------|-----------|
|  1   |    1      |
|  2   |    3      |
|  3   |    2      |
|  4   |    1      |
|  5   |    1      |
```

What would the best way to achieve this be?

Thanks, any tips or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unnest()`:

```
select u.el, count(*)
from t cross join
     unnest(t.array) u(el)
group by u.el;
```